# Perform operations on last iteration values using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I have two datasets.

df

```
Name     Date        Quantity
ZMTD    2018-06-30     1000
ZMTD    2018-05-31     975
ZMTD    2018-04-30     920
ZMTD    2018-03-30     900
ZMTD    2018-02-28     840
ZMTD    2018-01-31     820
ZMTD    2017-12-30     760
ZMTD    2017-11-31     600
ZMTD    2017-10-30     1200
ZMTD    2017-09-31     1170
ZMTD    2017-08-30     1090
ZMTD    2017-07-30     1100
```

df2

```
Name     Date        Factor
KOC    2018-01-15     0.5
ZMTD   2017-11-10     1.5
ZMTD   2018-03-20     2.5 
BND    2016-03-20     25
```

I am trying to divide the the column 'Quantity' in df with the column 'Factor' in df2 on all rows that satisfy the condition df['Date'] < df2['Date'].

I wrote the following code

```
name = df['Name'].iloc[0]
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row[0] == name:
        factor_date = row[1]
        ratio = row[2]
        for j, rows in df.iterrows():
            new_quantity = rows[2]
            if (rows[1] < factor_date):
                new_quantity = (new_quantity / ratio)
                df.at[i, 'Quantity'] = new_quantity
```

when I run this code, I expect the following values

```
Name     Date        Quantity
ZMTD    2018-06-30     1000
ZMTD    2018-05-31      975   
ZMTD    2018-04-30      920
ZMTD    2018-03-30      900
ZMTD    2018-02-28      336
ZMTD    2018-01-31      328
ZMTD    2017-12-30      304
ZMTD    2017-11-31      240
ZMTD    2017-10-30      320
ZMTD    2017-09-31      312
ZMTD    2017-08-30      290.66
ZMTD    2017-07-30      293.34
```

But I get the values where the Quantity column is divided by the latest Factor column value 2.5 but not on the values which are initially divided by 1.5

I was wondering if we can save the values of the initial iteration and then run the new iteration on the previous values using iterrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you what you seek:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left', suffixes=('', '2'))

df['Factor'] = ((df['Date'] < df['Date2']).astype(int) * df['Factor']).replace(0, 1)

df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Date']).agg({'Quantity': 'max', 'Factor': 'prod'}).reset_index()

df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'] / df['Factor']

df[['Name', 'Date', 'Quantity']].sort_values(['Name', 'Date'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

#    Name        Date     Quantity
#0   ZMTD  2018-06-30  1000.000000
#1   ZMTD  2018-05-31   975.000000
#2   ZMTD  2018-04-30   920.000000
#3   ZMTD  2018-03-30   900.000000
#4   ZMTD  2018-02-28   336.000000
#5   ZMTD  2018-01-31   328.000000
#6   ZMTD  2017-12-30   304.000000
#7   ZMTD  2017-11-31   240.000000
#8   ZMTD  2017-10-30   320.000000
#9   ZMTD  2017-09-31   312.000000
#10  ZMTD  2017-08-30   290.666667
#11  ZMTD  2017-07-30   293.333333
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I solved it using another method by rewriting the file name and reading it through it, and then calculating the quantity. So basically, I wrote the same file n times if n rows are present in df2. This is such an optimized solution that saves so much time. Thank you once again :)

Comment: You are welcome, I tried making it faster but I'm not sure where to cut on code :)

Comment: Compared to my code, this is now as fast as it could be :)